# How to avoid Blank space insertion at the beginning of the String in Java while using Split() function

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Here is the code Snippet.

```
public static void main(String...strings){
        String s="google";
        String[] s1=s.split("");
        System.out.println(s1[0]);
        System.out.println(s1.length);
    }
```

I'm trying to split the String s around each character. But the problem is while splitting a blank space is getting introduced at the begining of the splitted array.
Which is giving me output length 7 instead of 6. and since it can't have trailing spaces as split here will be getting passed as `split("", 0)`, so it has to be at the beginning
To test i printed `s1[0]` and its giving blank space indeed.

My question is how to avoid such problem. I need to use split.

What is actually happening here.?

[IdeOne Link](http://ideone.com/GvIXPt)

Comment: *a blank space is getting introduced at the begining of the splitted array* - Nope. It isn't.. I just tried..

Comment: The code you have posted gives you the array `["g", "o", "o", "g", "l", "e"]`. It does not produce the error you're saying that you have. Please check that you've posted the actual code that you're having issues with.

Comment: it works fine..the output is  g
6

Comment: @TheLostMind Check IdeOneLink above for length of splitted array

Comment: It does produce what he say it does. `[, g, o, o, g, l, e]` legit question. Stop posting check your code as answers.

Comment: @AnkurAnand what's your expected output?

Comment: @AnkurAnand - Print each string in the array and check

Comment: @AvinashRaj output length as 6 instead of 7 so mean to say no blank space at starting of array

Comment: @Shahzeb Yeah i checked it worked but need to know also this behavior of split function in java.. how it actually working here

Comment: @AnkurAnand - You should check why you are getting this issue in the first place. Check whether the input is what you think it is. Print the input and its length

Comment: @TheLostMind Input is what it's and length is also 6 .. have already checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `String.split()` behaves differently in Java 7 (used by IdeOne) and Java 8 (probably used by some of the commenters and answerers). In the Java 8 JavaDoc documentation for `String.split()`, the following is written:

> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array. A zero-width match at the beginning however never produces such empty leading substring.

So, according to Java 8, `"google".split("")` is equal to `["g","o","o","g","l","e"]`.

This remark is not present in the Java 7 documentation, and indeed, in Java 7 it seems to be that `"google".split("")` is equal to `["", "g","o","o","g","l","e"]`.

(Both in Java 7 and in Java 8 empty strings at the end of the array are removed.)

The best solution seems to be to just add code to ignore the first string if it is empty. (Note that the `split("\\B")` solution suggested in another answer yields unexpected results when your input consists of more than one word.)

Comment: The Explanation i was looking for .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Split your input according to non-word boundary.

```
string.split("\\B");
```

`\B` matches between two non-word characters or two word characters.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xO9iG4/1)

**OR**

split according to the below regex.

```
string.split("(?<!^)(?:\\B|\\b)(?!$)");
```

Comment: may i know the reason?

Comment: I do not know who voted you down but I have given +1. Your answer does work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj your solution work :) .. but i need to know the reason why split is behaving that way

Comment: because it splits the input also according to the empty char which exists before the first char.

Comment: why there is 3 downvotes? It works perfectly for his particular input.

Comment: You change the meaning of the regex when you use `\\B`. The original split split the string into characters, while your regex split at non-word boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried your code & there is no problem.

I think there may be a **white space by mistake** & that causes the problem.

use `trim()` to avoid such mistakes .

```
    String s="google";
    String[] s1=s.trim().split("");
    System.out.println(s1[0]);
    System.out.println(s1.length);
```

Comment: It's not the cause of the problem. See the accepted answer.